# Why am I getting incorrect response_json from my request in python

Tags: python, python-requests, spotify, youtube-dl

I am trying to automate adding songs to spotify using python. 
Here in the code I am trying to search for the song using the song_name and the artist name and use the spotify api to get the URI of the song. (https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search/search/)

However the response I am getting is invalid i.e it doesnt return the list of songs with uris, it just returns back the query or the request that I am sending in to the API.

e.g {'tracks': {'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=track%3AYEAH+RIGHT+artist%3AJoji&type=track&offset=0&limit=20', 'items': [], 'limit': 20, 'next': None, 'offset': 0, 'previous': None, 'total': 0}}

```
def get_spotify_uri(self, song_name, artist):
    """Search For the Song"""
    query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track:{}%20artist:{}&type=track".format(
        song_name,
        artist
    )
    response = requests.get(
        query,
        headers={
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(spotify_token)
        }
    )
    response_json = response.json()
    print(response_json)
    songs = response_json["tracks"]["items"]

    # only use the first song
    uri = songs[0]["uri"]

    return uri            



Error: response
{'tracks': {'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=track%3ANext+%28Album+Version%29+artist%3AThe+Weeknd&type=track&offset=0&limit=20', 'items': [], 'limit': 20, 'next': None, 'offset': 0, 'previous': None, 'total': 0}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nikhil/Crypy/spotifyplaylist.py", line 149, in <module>
    cp.add_song_to_playlist()
  File "/home/nikhil/Crypy/spotifyplaylist.py", line 124, in add_song_to_playlist
    self.get_liked_videos()
  File "/home/nikhil/Crypy/spotifyplaylist.py", line 77, in get_liked_videos
    "spotify_uri": self.get_spotify_uri(song_name, artist)
  File "/home/nikhil/Crypy/spotifyplaylist.py", line 119, in get_spotify_uri
    uri = songs[0]["uri"]
```

Comment: edit your question, include the response code and text within it, also have you obtained the `oAuth` token from https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token firstly?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I have added the error response and yes I have obtained the oAuth token from the given link

Comment: I noticed your edit now. Isn't that response the one you get simply because no tracks matching your query were found?

Comment: hi @user2464424, I get this response after getting a match on the track. The thing about this script is that this sometimes work and most of the times it doesnt and I have no idea.

Comment: Your example works only if you remove the `(Album+Version)` bit: `?q=track:Next+artist:The+Weeknd&type=track`. I'm having the impression this problem is merely a matter of bad search queries. I suggest you gather a whole bunch of examples of queries that don't give any results even tho the tracks exist on spotify and create an algorithm that strips away search terms that usually hamper the search.

Comment: @user2464424 you are right, the error was being triggered by times which returns no uri. I added some basic replace statement to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer because I couldn't fit the entire thing in a comment. I just wanted to say that I was successful with the barebones code below that however uses `urllib`, which might not be what you are looking for given that you use the `requests` library. Perhaps it can be useful for comparison purposes (tested in python 3.8):

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
import base64, json

# fill with your own
client_id = b"insert_here_your_client_id"
client_secret = b"insert_here_your_client_secret"

# ask for authorization
query = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
postdata = urllib.parse.urlencode({"grant_type": "client_credentials"})
postheaders = {'Authorization': "Basic "+base64.b64encode( client_id+b':'+client_secret ).decode('latin-1')}
req = urllib.request.Request(query, data=postdata.encode('latin-1'), headers=postheaders)
req = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('latin-1')
req = json.loads(req)

# do the search query
query = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=track:Castles%20artist:Freya&type=track"
req = urllib.request.Request(query, data=None, headers={'Authorization': "Bearer "+req['access_token']})
req = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('latin-1')
print(req)
```

Comment: Hi, can we skip the authorization part via hardcoding the token? or is the authorization necessary?

Comment: @invalidexplorer in [the docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow) it says in the response there's a `"expires_in"` field, so yes, the token will expire in x seconds.